# Python segmentation fault when threading modified ackermann function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm new to python, excuse if I don't write it completely 'the python way'
But I wanted to make one of the slow algorithms to calculate in parallel, and python seemed to have easy solution for that. But... I bumped into a wall.

I'm trying to thread calculation of an optimized modified ackermann function. Without threads it does like 1000 results in a minute, and I want it to be calculated in parallel as I can start with any input.

So here is an example of my code (stripped most of the gimmicks for deciding where to start from). Also I hardcoded it to be only on a single thread as I want to see it passing that 4-5 result mark when I get the segmentation fault.

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
sys.setrecursionlimit(999999)

# max_threads = os.cpu_count()
max_threads = 1

print('Available CPU cores: ' + str(max_threads))


def calc(r0, r1, r7, memory):
    key = str(r0) + '.' + str(r1)

    if key in memory:
        return memory[key]

    if r0 == 0:
        memory[key] = (r1 + 1) % 32768
        return memory[key]

    if r1 == 0:
        memory[key] = calc(r0 - 1, r7, r7, memory)
        return memory[key]

    memory[key] = calc(r0 - 1, calc(r0, r1 - 1, r7, memory), r7, memory)
    return memory[key]


def batch_calc():
    start = 0
    end = 1000

    for reg in range(start, end):
        print('Trying with register: ' + str(reg))
        memory = dict()
        result = calc(4, 1, reg, memory)
        if result == 6:
            print('Found it! Register: ' + str(reg))
            break


threads = []

for i in range(max_threads):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=batch_calc)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
```

The result I get is:

```
Available CPU cores: 1
Trying with register: 0
Trying with register: 1
Trying with register: 2
Trying with register: 3
Trying with register: 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The dump is:

```
systemd-coredump[5385]: Process 5382 (python) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                                     Stack trace of thread 5383:
                                                     #0  0x00007f93f9ce0e78 n/a (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #1  0x00007f93f9ce4f81 _PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords_SizeT (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #2  0x00007f93f9ce58a9 n/a (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #3  0x00007f93f9caeeb8 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #4  0x00007f93f9cf7c5a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #5  0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #6  0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #7  0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #8  0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #9  0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #10 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #11 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #12 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #13 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #14 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #15 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #16 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #17 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #18 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #19 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #20 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #21 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #22 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #23 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #24 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #25 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #26 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #27 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #28 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #29 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #30 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #31 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #32 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #33 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #34 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #35 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #36 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #37 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #38 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #39 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #40 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #41 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #42 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #43 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #44 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #45 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #46 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #47 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #48 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #49 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #50 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #51 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #52 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #53 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #54 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #55 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #56 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #57 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #58 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #59 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #60 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #61 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #62 0x00007f93f9cf33cd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #63 0x00007f93f9c817db _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)

                                                     Stack trace of thread 5382:
                                                     #0  0x00007f93fa27a436 do_futex_wait.constprop.1 (libpthread.so.0)
                                                     #1  0x00007f93fa27a538 __new_sem_wait_slow.constprop.0 (libpthread.so.0)
                                                     #2  0x00007f93f9c2b529 PyThread_acquire_lock_timed (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #3  0x00007f93f9ce4922 n/a (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #4  0x00007f93f9c820a4 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #5  0x00007f93f9caec6f _PyMethodDescr_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #6  0x00007f93f9cf7aee _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #7  0x00007f93f9c3a069 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #8  0x00007f93f9c81982 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #9  0x00007f93f9cf3225 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #10 0x00007f93f9c3a069 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #11 0x00007f93f9c81982 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #12 0x00007f93f9cf3225 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #13 0x00007f93f9c3b08b _PyFunction_FastCallDict (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #14 0x00007f93f9cbd1df _PyObject_CallMethodId (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #15 0x00007f93f9d4bd21 n/a (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #16 0x00007f93f9d6c32f Py_FinalizeEx (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #17 0x00007f93f9d6e6eb n/a (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #18 0x00007f93f9d6f420 _Py_UnixMain (libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
                                                     #19 0x00007f93fa0ca223 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                                                     #20 0x000055f451c3877a _start (python3.7)
systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 5384/UID 0).
kernel: python[5383]: segfault at 7f93f76c5ff8 ip 00007f93f9ce0e78 sp 00007f93f76c6000 error 6 in libpython3.7m.so.1.0[7f93f9b32000+2e4000]
```

Comment: That's a pretty high recursion limit. The default limit protects you from runaway recursion that could chew up too much RAM, or cause a stack overflow of the underlying C stack. But you're bypassing that protection. BTW, all Python threads run on a single core. If you want to use more cores then you need to use multiprocessing.

Comment: What? All python threads run on a single core? How did I miss that... going back to the docs...

Comment: And btw, the recursion limit is not the problem, I was able to go pretty high and not crash anything. It crashes when I put all that into threading...

Comment: Ah, ok. But I bet the high recursion limit is a factor in the core dump. ;) But anyway, you should read about the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: You were correct, with multiprocessing I'm able to run all things in separate cores without any crashes. Thanks.

Comment: Still it would have been better if Python returns some meaningful error instead of Segmentation faults all the time...

Comment: Perhaps, but once the segfault happens it's too late for the Python interpreter to do much about it.